# C# Decryption to Python PyDes

Tags: c#, python, encryption

In C# I have a byte[24] byte array holding the Key for triple DES encryption/decryption. Everything works great in c#.

My question is, how can I use the same Byte Array in Python?

I am using the PyDes package and I am new to python so I don't know if it's PyDes that doesn't accept the byte array or it's me doing it wrong...

My Python code is below (I changed the data in the key for this example).

```
from pyDes import *

print ("Example of DES encryption using CBC mode\n")

key = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
arr = bytearray(key)

k = triple_des(key, CBC, pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
data = "DES encryption algorithm"
print ("Key      : %r" % k.getKey())
print ("Data     : %r" % data)

d = k.encrypt(data)
print ("Encrypted: %r" % d)

d = k.decrypt(d)
print ("Decrypted: %r" % d)
print ("")
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    k = triple_des(key, CBC, pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyDes.py", line 710, in __init__
    self.setKey(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyDes.py", line 727, in setKey
    self._padding, self._padmode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyDes.py", line 409, in __init__
    self.setKey(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyDes.py", line 414, in setKey
    self.__create_sub_keys()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyDes.py", line 462, in __create_sub_keys
    key = self.__permutate(des.__pc1, self.__String_to_BitList(self.getKey()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyDes.py", line 421, in __String_to_BitList
    data = [ord(c) for c in data]
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

---

Update. After installing python 3 and setting my key and IV to the bytes type, encryption works. The problem is, it doesn't decrypt properly.

The encrypted data in my c# program is:
"Hello World. This is just a test. Goodbye World."

It is decrypting in my python script as:
"\xc3n)\xf8J\xaf\xab\x01rld. This is just a test. Goodbye World."

What would cause half of this to get decrypted properly, but the first part not?

Comment: This code works fine for me.  What output do you see when you try to run it?

Comment: 3DES really, this is 2016, AES should be used for new work. 3DES is minimally secure, the 24 bytes are only a 168-bit key but due to the meet-in-the-middle attack, the effective security it provides is only 112 bits..

Comment: @zaph I agree. It's just that this isn't new work.

Comment: @JeffreyRennie The code is now "Fixed". I had the key set manually instead of using the key array.

Comment: OK, have they agreed on what year, decade or century the 3DES usage will be sunsetted? Or will it always be "next time"? I'm betting on the latter.

Comment: Note that the lsb of the key bytes is ignored to the key really is: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `CBC` should be `pyDes.CBC` and `PAD_PKCS5` should be `pyDes.PAD_PKCS5` in

```
k = triple_des(key, CBC, pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
```

change to :

```
k = triple_des(key, pyDes.CBC, pad=None, padmode= pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
```

See: [pyDes](https://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html).

Comment: I still get the same error. I'm guessing because pyDes is expecting a string instead of an array filled with ints. Maybe I should try another cryptography package.